# How to find a minimum spanning tree in complete undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

There is complete undirected graph, in which about 10000 vertices. Is there more better way to find a minimum spanning tree, than Kruskal's algorithm, Prim's algorithm or [Borůvka's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka%27s_algorithm)?

Comment: Prim with a custom, density-exploiting priority queue is O(n^2)-time, but every time I've seen a question like this in the past, it's been the case that the edge weights are Euclidean distances or something. Is that so for you as well?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, yeah, this is a my case too. I use Euclidean distances.

Comment: How many dimensions?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, there is 2 dimensions.